# Comment traduire « general reference question » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

Comment appeler une question dont la réponse se trouve facilement dans un ouvrage de référence tel qu'un dictionnaire ou une encyclopédie ? En anglais, on parle facilement de *general reference question*. Comment traduire de manière raisonnablement concise cette expression ?

Cette question est inspirée par [le motif de clôture de questions sur le site English Stack Exchange](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/faut-il-le-motif-de-cloture-question-trop-elementaire-do-we-want-a-general), dont le nom court est « *general reference* » et dont la définition est :

> *This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.*

Comment: Je dirais bien “question trop simple”.

Comment: La seule expression qui me vient en tête serait "question de culture générale", mais je ne suis pas très convaincu que ce soit une bonne traduction.

Comment: Une question dont la réponse est *triviale* ?

Comment: @Joubarc Ce n'est pas la même chose que *culture générale* : le sens d'un mot rare mais présent dans les dictionnaires usuels n'est pas de la culture générale, mais rentre dans « *general reference* ». A contrario, quelque chose qui est évident pour un francophone mais pas facile à trouver par écrit peut être de la culture générale sans être « *general reference* ». Ma propisition « trop élémentaire » a le même défaut.

Comment: @Laurent *Triviale* au sens mathématique du terme, oui, mais je ne crois pas qu'un non-mathématicien comprenne le mot dans le bon sens.

Comment: Vulgaire? Profane? Banale? Futile? Sans substance? Grossière? Franchement, j'aime mieux triviale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je rebondis sur le commentaire de Laurent. Ce n'est pas tant que la *question* soit trop simple, mais que les *réponses* (potentielles) seront trop simples (« *can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link* »).

Évidemment, ce n'est pas toujours possible *a priori* de déterminer si une question « simple » aura une réponse facile ou non, mais j'hésiterais très fortement à tout interdire en bloc.

Je crois que, comme pour la discussion sur les traductions ([ici](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/translation-questions/22#22), lire les commentaires aussi), **ce qui importe c'est le contexte** :

> On n'est pas contre les questions concernant un seul mot, *à condition* qu'il y ait un contexte qui rend la question plus intéressante et plus précise que ce à quoi pourrait répondre un dictionnaire.

**Alors...** *Question trop facile* ? Ou, la nuit porte conseil…

> *Question sans valeur ajoutée*

Comment: Ça ne répond pas à ma question, qui est de trouver une formulation concise. L'anglais y arrive bien avec « *general reference question* » : une question qui est en rapport avec une « *general reference* ». En français, on ne peut pas juxtaposer des mots comme ça.

Comment: @Gilles, how about "Question à faible valeur ajoutée"?

Comment: « Question sans valeur ajoutée », plutôt. J'aime bien.

Comment: @Gilles, ok, vendu :)

Answer (score 1):

La première réponse qui me vient serait

> Une question bateau

mais c'est sans doute d'un registre un peu trop familier.

> Une question élémentaire

est peut-être un peu plus soutenu. On peut même faire un rapport avec le cours élémentaire qui aborde des notions basiques (rapport à « *This question is too basic* »).

Answer (score 0):

D'après [cette description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason/88521#88521), ce serait selon moi:

> une question de paresseux

Un badge "partisan du moindre effort" pourrait alors être décerné. :)

Comment: Apte, mais un peu trop négatif.

Answer (score 0):

Une question bateau fonctionnerait parfaitement si l'on était dans un registre familier. 
Je penserais à question sans fond, ou banale.